# How to include the built in functions (e.g Math) in Macromedia Flash MX

Tags: flash, actionscript-2, macromedia

I have included the built-in function Math using

`#include "Math.as`"

while publishing (`.swf`) I'm getting an error:

```
Error in line 3. Math.as file not found.
```

Answer (score 1):

They should be top-level, meaning they are always accessible and you don't really need to import them.

Please take a look why **import** is different from **include**:

include statements are essentially a copy and paste of the content inside the included ActionScript file.

Why would you want to copy paste something that is already there?

EDIT:

If you've made your own, custom Math.as file and would like to use that, the error states that the path to your Math.as file is incorrect.